# Iframe in react component keeps reloading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, material-ui

My goal is to have a page where I show multiple iframes and I switch between them using a TabList component from mui.
What I want is to load each iframe only once to then be able to switch between tabs without having the iframe reloading again.
Here is what I currently do:

```
function DashViewer(props: any) {
  let { slug } = useParams();

  const [dashboardEntity, setDashboardEntity] = useState<any | null>(null);
  const [displayedEmbedRank, setDisplayedEmbedRank] = useState("0");
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const initialize = () => {
      currentUser.getIdToken(true).then(function (idToken: any) {
        fetch("/dashboards/viewer/", {
          method: "post",
          headers: {
            Authorization: idToken,
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ slug: slug }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) => {
            setDashboardEntity(responseData.data.dash_infos);

          });
      });
    };
    return initialize();
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
    setDisplayedEmbedRank(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Stack spacing={0}>

      <TabContext value={displayedEmbedRank}>
        <Box
          sx={{ borderBottom: 0 }}
          alignItems="center"
          justifyContent="center"
        >
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} centered>
            {dashboardEntity != null &&
              dashboardEntity.embeds.authorizations.map(
                (embed: any, rank: any) => (
                  <Tab label={embed.label} value={rank} />
                )
              )}
          </TabList>
        </Box>
      </TabContext>

      {dashboardEntity != null &&
        dashboardEntity.embeds.authorizations.map(
          (embed: any, rank: any) =>
           (rank == displayedEmbedRank  && (
                <Embed name={dashboardEntity.meta.name} i={rank} hide={false}/>
           )
            )
        )}

      {dashboardEntity != null &&
        dashboardEntity.embeds.authorizations.map(
          (embed: any, rank: any) =>
            rank != displayedEmbedRank  && (
                <Embed name={dashboardEntity.meta.name} i={rank} hide={true}/>
            )
        )}

    </Stack>
  );
}
```

The DashViewer components is where I generate my tabs and show a different Embed (see below) component based on a state controlled by the tabs. I pass a 'hide=true' prop on the Embed component
I want to show and false on the others.

```
function Embed(props: any) {

  return (
    <div {...(props.hide == true && { style: { display: "none" } })}>
        <Iframe name={props.name} i={props.i}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Embed is basically a wrapper around an Iframe component I made, I use the hide prop to hide the div if necessary.

```
function Iframe(props:any) {
    return (
        <iframe
        name={`embed-${props.i}`}
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        src={`/dashboards/viewer/${props.name}/${props.i}`}
        style={{
          display: "block",
          background: "#1F3B50",
          height: "calc(100vh - 60px)",
          width: "calc(100vw - 0px)",
          margin: "auto",
          border: "none",
        }}
      ></iframe>
    )
}
```

Iframe is very simple it just contains an iframe component.

Currently it switches iframes when I click the different tabs but it always reloads the whole iframe each time.
What I understand is that as displayedEmbedRank is part of the state, each Embed component is re-rendered each time the displayedEmbedRank state changes.
What I tried so far is trying React.memo() on Iframe as I thought it wouldn't re-render again if it already did for a set of given props, but it didn't seem to work either.